# Finding duplicate count in SQL

Tags: sql, duplicates, ansi-sql

I know how to return duplicates by doing the following:

```
select cust_name, cust_id, count(*)
from customers
group by cust_name, cust_id
having count(*) > 1;
```

What I want to know if there is a way to return a straight count of duplicates in the table, and not the associated values?

For example if the above query returned:

```
cust_name   cust_id count(*)
Fred        22789      2
Jim         45678      3
```

Is there a query I could write that would just return the number?

So

```
count(*)
   2
```

Or

```
count(*)
   5
```

Something like that. In reality the uniqueness could be a combo of 1 to N columns, the above example just shows 2 columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use a subquery:

```
select count(*) as num_with_duplicates,
       sum(cnt) as total_duplicate_count
from (select cust_name, cust_id, count(*) as cnt
      from customers
      group by cust_name, cust_id
      having count(*) > 1
     ) cc;
```